# Lack of proliferation of the WSDL Standard

Tags: web-services, api, wsdl, interpreter

disclaimer: 
I think this question is appropriate for this site because there may be a technical limitation I overlooked, as opposed to a mere preference based discussion.

Hello,

Is there a reason why WSDL is not more widely used in public API creation? It gives instructions for programming languages to construct data objects and code themselves, by use of a WSDL interpreter.

For instance, the Facebook API is on github in each specific language they support. And then for some niche applications, individuals have made their own Facebook integrations in other languages. Wouldn't a simple solution just be one WSDL file and everyone else could use WSDL interpreters in their language of choice to recreate the API without all the trial and error?

Comment: When you find a technical limitation, you can discuss it here. Until then, I'm voting to close as "not constructive".

Comment: @JohnSaunders  catch 22, I posted it here to find a technical limitation

Comment: But you have no reason to believe that there _is_ a technical limitation. In any case, even if there were such a limitation, nobody here could solve that for you.

Comment: @JohnSaunders unless they had experience with WSDL of course. I am wondering why this isn't the preferred means of porting objects across languages. I am wondering if there is a competing standard. I am wondering why it seems that people generally just opt to re-write objects in their porting efforts.

Comment: WSDL simply doesn't address those porting issues. It addresses a simpler set of use cases - web services and other messaging systems. For instance, WSDL does not describe behavior of objects, and does not include many things present in modern OO languages. How do you describe a constructor in WSDL? Or even `enum`, really?

Comment: @JohnSaunders see, that was a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSDL simply doesn't address those porting issues. It addresses a simpler set of use cases - web services and other messaging systems. For instance, WSDL does not describe behavior of objects, and does not include many things present in modern OO languages. How do you describe a constructor in WSDL? Or even enum, really?